# Phpunit yii: two fixtures to one table

Tags: yii, phpunit

In phpunit, with Yii, is possibile to create more fixtures for the same table?
I would like to have different fixtures folders to be used with different unit test, to avoid problems between the various test file.

Comment: Use [factories](https://github.com/ddinchev/yii-factory-girl) instead of fixtures and the problem goes away ...

Comment: @Darhazer check out Willem Renzema answer because it works. I think he deserves your bounty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the fixture folder for each test by adding the following to your test classes:

```
protected function setUp()
{
    $this->getFixtureManager()->basePath = 'path/to/fixtures';
    parent::setUp();
}
```

With this, you can have your tests use whichever set of fixtures you want.

Make sure to call `parent::setUp()`, and to call it after setting the `basePath` property, as that is what actually loads the fixtures.

See also [CDbFixtureManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbFixtureManager).

Comment: use tearDown to reverse setUp